# Update does not apply condition in Postgres trigger

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have three tables like these:

Orders(product_id (Foreign Key), personnel_id (Foreign Key), order_count)

Product(product_id (Primary Key), price)

Retailer(personnel_id (Primary Key), commission)

I'm trying to create a trigger that adds to a retailer's commission with every order that is placed with his help.

Here's my code for the trigger. But it seems like it has a bug and it's updating every single record in the Retailers table with each insert (or some other bug that's causing wrong results in the Retailers table)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_commission() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $table$
BEGIN
    update "Retailers" rt
    set commission = commission + (res.order_count * res.price * 0.005)
    from
    (select r.personnel_id, o.order_count, p.price from
    "Orders" o left join "Retailers" r
        on r.personnel_id = o.personnel_id
    left join "Products" p
        on o.product_id = p.product_id) as res
    where NEW.personnel_id = res.personnel_id;
    return NEW;
END;

$table$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER new_order
  AFTER INSERT
  ON "Orders"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_commission();
```